# MaxMind GeoIP CSV to .dat

Tags: linux, csv, geoip

I need to put local IP addresses into MaxMind GeoIP DB.
I've downloaded the CSV and adding new IP addresses and locations is easy.
I've found two tools that do csv to dat for MaxMind GeoIP but I can't get them work.

With python script:

```
./csv2dat.py -w custom_geoip.dat mmcountry working.csv 
File "./csv2dat.py", line 69
print "error: database types don't match"
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Also, I've tried to compile cpp script (https://github.com/dankamongmen/sprezzos-world/blob/master/packaging/geoip/debian/src/geoip-csv-to-dat.cpp) but I get large strace.

I've tried with new and old MaxMind DB. is there any other tool?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`geoip-csv-to-dat.cpp` - is the part of [`geoip-bin`](https://packages.debian.org/ru/jessie/geoip-bin) package and could be installed from Debian or Ubuntu repository if it is your linux distributive.

```
apt-get install geoip-bin
/usr/lib/geoip/geoip-generator --help
```

UPDATE:
digging into the source uncovered that maxmind country and city csv databases got completely different formats so you have to provide different bunches of arguments to process it.

For country database:

```
/usr/lib/geoip/geoip-generator -v -o custom_geoip.dat working.csv
```

For city database:

```
/usr/lib/geoip/geoip-generator -v -o custom_geoip.dat -t \
GEOIP_CITY_EDITION_REV1 -l working-locations.csv working-blocks.csv
```

As for `csv2dat.py` - looks like you are trying to execute `Python 2` script with `Python 3` interpreter. Try:

```
python2.7 csv2dat.py -w custom_geoip.dat mmcountry working.csv
```

Comment: This looks like the perfect answer but when I run it I get `/usr/lib/geoip/geoip-generator:GeoLite2-City-Blocks-IPv4.csv:2: Wrong number of fields`. Any ideas what the fields should be for this to work? The fields I have are 'network geoname_id, registered_country_geoname_id, represented_country_geoname_id, is_anonymous_proxy, is_satellite_provider, postal_code, latitude, longitude, accuracy_radius' as per the latest geolite city download.